# How does Recommend Close work and why does it instantly complete review?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

Just ran across an interesting review item in the Low Quality Posts queue:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1635862
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1635442

What caused me to look at it? A new review option I hadn't seen before: **Recommend Close**

I'm assuming this has always existed and I've just never noticed it before, and it probably works similar to the Recommend Deletion button. However, what concerns me is that one action instantly completes review for the item. This seems like a bug to me because it doesn't follow the same criteria for completion as other action types:

- [Close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1623174)
- [Recommend Deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1635802)

So how exactly does this one work since it obviously doesn't work like everything else in that review queue? Should a single Recommend Close action dismiss it?

Comment: This is why I like to review more in the flagged section, as there is less ambiguity. Whilst the /review layout is nice, the tried and true tools never fail me.

Comment: Just thinking wildly off-the-cuff here; but perhaps recommend close will put something in the close queue, as though it had gotten a (unicorn) vote for close?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Recommend Close" brings up the "flag to close" dialog (the same one you get by clicking "flag" and then "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate").

Since questions with close flags are sent to the Close Queue, "Recommend Close" basically ends up punting the question from one queue to another. Also, note that only people with between 2k and 3k rep see "Recommend Close", since you need 2k to review low quality posts, and 3k to close.

**EDIT**

<kbd>Recommend Close</kbd> no longer dequeues an item from the Low Quality queue.

Comment: So, why doesn't similar functionality work for the normal "Close" option? A close vote from a normal user would kick it into the Close Votes queue too, yet that action doesn't complete review in LQP.

Comment: I see your point now-- it would be more consistent if either Close dequeued, or if Recommend Close didn't. Trying to decide which makes more sense

Comment: Could you explain [this review item](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1640114) to me? I see four Close actions there and a Recommend Close action. Then I went to the question itself and saw that it only had *two* close votes. The first two people who reviewed that item do not have 3,000 reputation and thus cannot vote to close, so why did it record a Close action? This all looks very confusing... o.o

Comment: Strange.. close *flags*, rather than close *votes*, were correctly recorded for those 2 users, but I still can't figure out why the review decisions were recorded as Close rather than Recommend Close.