# Low Quality review queue erroneously showing "Close" instead of "Recommended Close"?

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts

I was in the Low Quality Review queue, and the following review confused me:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3400690

It's showing eight "Close votes", which should be more than enough to close a question.  I checked the question's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20098844/revisions), and it wasn't somehow closed, then re-opened in the middle of the review.

So I then checked on each of the users, and noticed that the majority of them are under 3000 reputation, meaning they can only "Recommend Close".

However, all reviews are simply showing as "Close", which is extremely confusing.  Is this a bug, or possibly an undocumented change related to [How many "Recommend Close" votes is too many?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204705/how-many-recommend-close-votes-is-too-many)?

---

Another recent example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3437631

Comment: @animuson - thanks for the edit.  Also, that's funny -- in three weeks, I've now been involved in two Low Quality Review items that have netted **14+** reviews before terminal action was taken.  Good times.

Comment: This bug still [occurs](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3976109) as of February 5, 2014.

Comment: And it [still occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5449665). I don't understand why the system lets sub-3kers review that queue if their votes don't count. Either they've enough experience to decide if questions should be closed or they haven't, but letting them think they have and then silently ignoring their votes is stupid.

Comment: [Still occurs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305297/why-do-recommend-close-reviews-show-up-as-close-reviews-in-the-low-quality-p) going into 2018.