# Why do "Recommend Close" reviews show up as "Close" reviews in the Low Quality Posts review queue?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts, wording

[This low quality review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/53755) has two reviews: one (from [S.L. Barth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/168333/s-l-barth)) to **close** and another to **recommend close** (because [Mureinik](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/223467/mureinik) doesn’t have enough reputation to vote to close). But for both reviews, the review choice they picked shows up as **Close**.

> [image: Close?]

Is this intended, or is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

I suspect this is a bug, because for deletion, we also have two [different votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/53740): **delete** and **recommend deletion**, both of which show up properly as other's review choices. [This review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18297206) also shows that the user picked **Recommend Close**.

Comment: I edited about this topic as the anonymous editor...the two options are the same review, but for users with enough rep to vote to close or delete, it also casts a respective vote at the same time.

Comment: @gparyani I see no reason why not to add word “Recommend”  in resolution.

Comment: @gparyani the question is about the wording being used, not the actual action.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened, and the older one closed as a duplicate, because that report is much older and more likely to be ignored by the development team, and this one contains more information and a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that's useful here - the *review outcome* is more important than the *action* - and that's an informational thing to let you know what someone thought of the review, rather than a log of the action.

Comment: In some edge cases there are might be more then 5 close votes. This is confusing. Signing votes from the <3k users with “Recommend” would be better choice. Unfortunately I don’t have a link to English site, but you can see on [ruSO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41223392#41223392). There are 13 close votes.

Comment: I agree with @alex on this one. It's not really a bug, just something that can confuse people, and can be easily improved by changing the wording.